# How to make scheduled query in BigQuery less verbose?

Tags: google-bigquery

Using the console GUI, I managed to set up jobs to trigger and send an email notification in the event a condition in the data (SQL query) is met.

The email is being sent successfully and the process works as expected, however, when sending the message through Outlook, the email is very verbose and include gibberish that is not needed - is there a way in settings or through code to make the message less verbose ? - see below for reference;

All i need really to display in the email is below yellow highlighted line; thank you

[image]

Comment: I notice this post was downvoted, this is a free-expression platform obviously so downvotes are more than welcome, it would however help to know why this got downvoted; that way i can improve future posts/questions - code cannot be displayed in every single post- especially when the post is related to a GUI functionality - thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Looks like in the documentation it states that `The messages are **not** configurable`
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-run-notifications#email_notifications

But as an alternatively, you could publish to a pubsub topic instead.  This would allow you to access the full payload and extract the portions you want.
Steps to configure pubsub:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-run-notifications#notifications

The payload looks like this:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs.runs#TransferRun

Comment: it looks like i may lack appropriate permissions to enable pub-sub API but this appears to be a solution to the problem (once i get permissions) so thank you Daniel !